# How to insert a function in attributes?

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js, loops, single-page-application

I'm trying to loop through the `cost_classification_options` array and replace underscores with spaces, at the same time, capitalize the first letter of each string. I've done a method `convertToTitleCase(str)`, to do this, but doesn't seem to work. How can I insert convertToTitleCase(str) method correctly in `:options` (https://vue-multiselect.js.org/)?

```js
<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
<script>
import Form from 'vform'
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

export default {
    components: {
        Multiselect
    },
    data: () => ({
        errors: {},
        form: new Form({
            designation_id: [],
            position_id: [],
            cost_classification: []
        }),
        designation_options: [],
        position_options: [],
        cost_classification_options: ['direct_labor', 'indirect_labor', 'general_and_admin']
    }),
    methods: {
        async convertToTitleCase(str) {
            const arr = str.split('_');
            const result = [];
            for (const word of arr) {
                result.push(word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase());
            }
            return result.join(' ');
        },
    },
    created: function() {
        this.getDesignationNames();
        this.getPositionNames();
    },
}
</script>
```

```html
<multiselect
  v-model="form.cost_classification"
  :options="cost_classification_options"
  :multiple="false"
  :taggable="false"
  :tabindex="6"
></multiselect>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `async` keyword from the first of the method:

```
methods: {
        convertToTitleCase(str) {
            const arr = str.split('_');
            const result = [];
            for (const word of arr) {
                result.push(word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase());
            }
            return result.join(' ');
        },
    },
```

Create a `computed` property and convert all of options with the method:

```
computed: {
  selectOptions() {
    return this.cost_classification_options.map(opt => this.convertToTitleCase(opt))
  },
},
```

Change the template to this:

```
<multiselect
  v-model="form.cost_classification"
  :options="selectOptions"
  :multiple="false"
  :taggable="false"
  :tabindex="6"
></multiselect>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the logic complex. You can simply achieve it by iterating the options array in the `mounted()` hook.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
  },
  data: {
    cost_classification: [],
    cost_classification_options: ['direct_labor', 'indirect_labor', 'general_and_admin']
  },
  mounted() {
      this.cost_classification_options = this.cost_classification_options.map(opt => {
        const arr = opt.split('_');
        let str = '';
        for (const word of arr) {
          str += word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase() + ' ';
        }
        return str.trim();
      })
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.3/dist/vue-multiselect.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.3/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <multiselect 
    v-model="cost_classification" 
    :options="cost_classification_options"
    :multiple="false"
    >
  </multiselect>
  <pre>{{ cost_classification }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great solution as well. Thank you @Rohit!

Comment: Glad that it helps you!